# Proper File Structure For Sending E-Mails In Django

Tags: django, django-email

I'm sending many e-mails from within my Django views like this

```
if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            # email contents
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
            full_name = first_name + ' ' + surname
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            try:
                html_content = """
                <p>HEADING</p>
                
                <p>Sent from: """+ full_name +""".</p>

                <p>Email address: """+ from_email +""".</p>
                """

                email = EmailMessage('TITLE', html_content, 'example@gmail.com', ['example@gmail.com'])
                email.content_subtype = "html"
                email.send()

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')

            return redirect('example', first_name=first_name)
```

But I'm sure there has to be a standard file structure and way to separate the logic when sending e-mails.

If there is, or if anyone has any tidy ways to organise the contents of many emails rather than having them bloating my views, please share :).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that the following way:

First of all, will create an HTML template somewhere in my templates folder.

*somewhere/templates/some_email.html*

```
<p>HEADING</p>
<p>Sent from: {{ full_name }}.</p>
<p>Email address: {{ from_email }}.</p>
```

Then two helper functions, one for rendering and one for sending.

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import loader


Recipient_s = Union[List[str], Tuple[str], str]


def render_body(template_name: str, context: dict = None) -> str:
    """
    Load template by given name, pass it context
    and render as a string.
    """
    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    return template.render(context)


def send_email(
    subject: str,
    template_name: str,
    context: dict,
    to: Recipient_s,
    bcc: Recipient_s = None,
    cc: Recipient_s = None,
    reply_to: Recipient_s = None,
):

    if not to:
        return

    body = render_body(template_name, context)

    email = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject,
        body=body,
        to=[to],
        bcc=[bcc] if bcc else None,
        cc=[cc] if cc else None,
        reply_to=[reply_to] if reply_to else None,
    )

    # Setting main content
    email.content_subtype = "html"

    email.send()
```

and just call the function from view like below:

```
send_email(subject='BLABLABLA', template_name='some_email.html', context={'first_name': 'John', 'from_email': 'john@example.com'}...)
```